# Computing limit of sequence of sets defined on indicator function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I believe, this problem comes from the definition of a sequence of sets where the limit of the sequence is defined as through indicator function is equivalent to the infimum-supremum definition. I am still not able to argue clearly in this case of the indicator function (multi-definition). So here goes the exact question-

Let ($\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}$) be a probability space. We define the indicator function as

$$\textbf{1}_\textit{A}(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
1 & if  &\omega \in \textit{A} \\
0 & if & \omega \notin \textit{A}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\textit{A}_1, \textit{A}_2 , .... \in \mathcal{F}$. We say that $\textit{A}_n \to \textit{A} $ if $n \to \infty$ if $\textbf{1}_{A_n}(\omega)=\textbf{1}_{A}(\omega)$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$. Show that $\textit{A} \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\textit{A}_n) \to \mathbb{P}(\textit{A})$

Comment: If $1_A = 1_B$ then $A= B$. Do you mean that for each $\omega$ that there exists some $N$ such that $1_{A_n}(\omega) = 1_A(\omega)$ for all $n \ge N$?

Comment: But how to argue with limiting sets?

Comment: I think you want to say that this is true for all sufficiently large $n$.  I'm not sure if $n$ depends on $\omega$ or not.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The question defines $A_n \to A$ as $A_n = A$.

Comment: n is just an index of the sequence. As n tends to infinity, $\textit{A}_n \to \textit{A}$

Comment: @copper.hat But according to that definition, each $A_n = A,$ so the question is trivial.  It can't be what the OP intends.

Comment: @saulspatz: That is my point.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes indeed.  I misread your comment; sorry.

Comment: See the second definition which is what I intend to say while defining the limit of the sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#The_two_definitions

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal: Surely you mean the first?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you meant to write that $A_n \to A$ **iff** $\lim_n 1_{A_n}(\omega) = 1_A(\omega)$ for all $\omega$.

If this is the case, the dominated convergence theorem is your friend:

$P A_n=\int 1_{A_n} \to \int 1_A = PA$.

Comment: to start writing integrals, you need first to show $1_A$ is measurable and integrable, for this we should establish $A \in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: This follows from $A=\cup_n \cap_{k \ge n} A_k$.

Comment: may be i misread OPs initial comments. aren't $A = \bigcup\limits_n A_n$?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the OP is asking. The question equates $A_n \to A$ **iff** $A_n = A$, which must be a mistake.